# Rapidfire Cannon on Assassins, concern over range

Tags: teamfight-tactics

When I'm playing assassins a common counter is phantom dancer or Yordle miss chances. The best way to counter that is rapidfire cannon which prevents missing.  Which champs should it go on, for example in a 6 Assassin 4 Ninja comp?

I've had bad experiences with putting RFC on certain heroes, for example using it with Miss Fortune caused her to stand far away from the target and fire her ult in such a way that it doesn't reach the enemy. Same issue with Ahri.

Is there such a concern regarding assassins? I've noticed that the ult range for Akali and Kat are quite short. Those are typically the 2 main carries in an Assassin comp. Maybe the RFCs should go on Zed or Evelyn instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that Rengar makes the most out of Rapidfire Cannon, as his ability gives him 100% crit chance for a while after jumping, you should also be able to hit Zed's ability as well as Kha'zix's, Kha'zix will just need to walk up to his target a little bit